# Multi tenant Federated gateway with Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, ws-federation

I have an Identity server 4 application with several applications connected to it.  These applications are multi tenant separated by the sub-domain name.

I am trying to set up Azure AD for each of these tenants the problem is that additional tenants can be added on the fly at anytime.  I cant add each tenant in the startup.  Is there a way to automate live loading of additional federated authentication methods?

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddWsFederation(options =>
{
    // MetadataAddress represents the Active Directory instance used to authenticate users.
    options.MetadataAddress = "https://<ADFS FQDN or AAD tenant>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml";

    // Wtrealm is the app's identifier in the Active Directory instance.
    // For ADFS, use the relying party's identifier, its WS-Federation Passive protocol URL:
    options.Wtrealm = "https://localhost:44307/";

    // For AAD, use the App ID URI from the app registration's Properties blade:
    options.Wtrealm = "https://wsfedsample.onmicrosoft.com/bf0e7e6d-056e-4e37-b9a6-2c36797b9f01";
});
```

Comment: You could potentially use OpenID Connect setup to the "common" authority, and define an event handler for the redirect to identity provider event which replaced the authority with the tenant's authority. Then you'd need to also validate the issuer after they return to see that it is what is expected.

Comment: No idea if you can do it with ws-fed. Any particular reason you are using it by the way?

Comment: @juunas becouse WS-fed was the only thing i could find that would let me set up multiple Azure AD's  If you have another idea i would haply start Googling

Comment: @DaImTo probably [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/5a6b6c90b6e32ecab4975c546228cc63199f168b/src/AuthSamples/samples/DynamicSchemes) sample is what you are looking for. But consider [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4629) related issue

Comment: @d_f any idea how to get the code for the first one its in a tree cloning master doesnt return it.

Comment: @DaImTo as I can see, there are not more than five documents -- why not to copy&paste the code. actually the essential part is [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5a6b6c90b6e32ecab4975c546228cc63199f168b/src/AuthSamples/samples/DynamicSchemes/Controllers/AuthController.cs) controller and the [view](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5a6b6c90b6e32ecab4975c546228cc63199f168b/src/AuthSamples/samples/DynamicSchemes/Pages/Index.cshtml) to list the schemas as it was mentioned in the description

Comment: was kind of hoping to run it but from what i can read it doesnt acutally work.